# why my symfony routing is not working?

Tags: php, symfony

hi i have a problem with my routing in symfony. my routing_dev looks like:

```
_test:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /test
```

then i have a controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="_test")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

and when i try to run the /test i get the message:

```
No route found for "GET /test"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

i dont know where the error is. i need your help. how to find the problem?

EDIT: I'm working with the app_dev.php not app.php

Comment: run this in your console: app/console router:debug - it might by very useful to determine what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must be sure that routing.yml import the file routing_dev.yml.

Then, you must define the $name variable passed in argument in the route. If this argument is optional, you can give it a default value.

Moreover, note that you can put the prefix directly in the annotation.

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog")
 */
class TheClassController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{name}", name="_test", defaults={"name" = "Jean"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
         return array('name'=>$name);
    }
}
```

After, you can run run the command `php app/console router:debug` for test the route.

Comment: for symfony 3.4: php bin/console debug:router

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Symfony 4 you just need to install **doctrine/annotations** package. To download it, in your terminal run:

```
composer require annotations
```

The command will download the package into your vendor folder and add new **annotations.yaml** file under **config/routes** folder. Make sure annotations.yaml has following lines:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

You do not need any additional route settings inside **config/routes.yaml** file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use http://your.site/app_dev.php/test url. Or copy your routing information to routing.yml (not routing_dev.yml)

Comment: do u have the route with the same name (name="_test")?

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually typing into your url /test? Because your route is just "/", the name you have given is used to generate that route from a template. If you want the url to be /test you should change your route parameter to `@Route("/test", name="test")`

Comment: okay, this now added a /test when i call "php app/console router:debug" but still i get No route found for "GET /test"

Answer (score 0):

you explicit have to set the route for an action. not just for the whole controller.

your routing.yml should look like:

```
mybundle_controller:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /test
```

your controller like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/") #Note you can omit this, since you set the prefix in the routing.yml
 * 
 */
public function indexAction($name)
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_test"
     * @Template()
     */
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

try to run `php app/console router:debug`

it should return you something like

```
_test                   ANY      /test/
```

Comment: hmm, i did it, but there is no line with _test

Comment: okay, this now added a @Route("/test", name="test") when i call "php app/console router:debug" but still i get No route found for "GET /test"

Comment: I did not the updated answer.. especially the part about the routing yml.